# Federated Identity Management

Tags: java, osgi, federated-identity

I'm looking for a way to pull user (eg. inetOrgPerson) information in a federated way.  For the most part, this information will come from LDAP but could come from secondary systems.  I've looked at things like Jasig's Person Directory (married to Spring and we don't use it) and ArisID (no examples of use, yet).  I'm working inside of OSGi and would like something that is already bundled but am willing to bundle things myself.  What other IM libraries out there should I consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found anything to fit my needs.  I created an OSGi bundle to which services get registered to aggregate data.  The services are defined by the interface they implement to look up users in different ways and can draw the data from any source.  The information is then cached by the aggregator while the session is valid.

So, in short, I didn't find anything out there that is simple enough to fit this.